# asyncstorage doesn't keep data

Tags: react-native, expo, photo, asyncstorage

I'm storing images in my app with asyncStorage, at first everything goes well, I store the images and am able to display them calling from storage. Now my problem is that the photos I stored don't stay in the storage forever, I am using expo in react-native and when I open my app like a week after having stored some photos, the displayed photos I stored are empty, but everything else I stored in my storage hasn't moved. Does anyone know why? And how I can fix this, allowing my photos to stay in storage?
Thanks!

Code : 
In my render I have 2 touchable opacity :

```
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.snap}>
          <Text>CAPTURE PHOTO</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>


        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.savePhoto()} style={{marginRight: 40}}>
          <Text>SAVE PHOTO</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
```

snap() function :

```
snap = async () => {
  if (this.camera) {
    let photo = await this.camera.takePictureAsync()
    if (photo) {
      this.setState({ imageuri: photo.uri })
    }
  }
}
```

Savephoto() function :

```
savePhoto() {
   const { goBack } = this.props.navigation
   var todayDate = moment(new Date()).format('dddd DD MMMM YYYY HH:mm:ss')
   this._storeData("image:" + todayDate, this.state.imageuri)
   goBack()
```

}

And my store data function :

```
_storeData = async (name, data) => {
  try {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('@MySuperStore:' + name, data)
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("failed storing data")
  }
}
```

Comment: you are saving image as  `base64` or  as URL in asyncstorage ?? it will be helpful if you share some code.

Comment: I added my code !, thx

Comment: Are you using [Expo's Camera](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/camera/)? The uri from `takePictureAsync()` is temporary. In the docs there it tells you how to permanently save it, or you could save the `base64` value.

Comment: Oh okay, yes I am using expo's camera and takePictureAsync(), i didn't read that part, thank you i'll go check it out !